# Triangles inside a bigger triangle

Tags: calculus, geometry, trigonometry

I am asked to show that angle $\angle BPC = 2v$, also that $AB= 1 + \cos(2v)$, how would one do that? I have tried applying the laws of sines, but I seem to get stuck.

[image]

Comment: Use obvious relations between angles : sum of angles of triangle equal to $\pi$, Chasles relation, and symmetry with regard to the line $(PQ)$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that $\triangle APQ\cong \triangle CPQ$ by RHS criterion for congruency. This is because $AP=PC$, $\angle PQA=\angle PQC$ and $PQ=PQ$.

Thus, $$\angle QAP=\angle QCP=v$$But $\angle ACB=90^{\circ}-v$ so we have $$\angle PCB= \angle ACB-\angle QCP= 90^{\circ}-2v.$$ and thus $\angle CPB=2v$.

This implies $PB=\cos 2v$ so the results are obtained.